# How to fix the following error while using Firebase in my JS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Error:

index.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js' does not provide an export named 'getDatabase' (at index.js:2:10)

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js'
import { getDatabase, ref, push } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js'
const appSettings = {
    databaseURL : 'https://playground-5d1ab-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/'
}
const app = initializeApp(appSettings);
const database = getDatabase(app);
const shoppingListInDB = ref(database, "shoppingList");

const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-field");
const cartBtn = document.getElementById("button-id");
const shoppingListEl = document.getElementById("shopping-list");
cartBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let inputValue = inputBtn.value;
    push(shoppingListInDB, inputValue);
    console.log(inputValue); 
    shoppingListEl.innerHTML += `<li>${inputValue}</li>`;
})
```

I am expecting that the details would show when I console.log them on the screen and would get added to the firebase.

Comment: Why you're using cdn links? Any possibility to install firebase in your pc?

Comment: However the error is there becaues you're trying to export something from a file that doesn't contain one

Comment: `import { getDatabase, ref, push } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js"`